# Joomla! 2.5+: Abuse a system plugin to create an URI addressable view

Tags: plugins, joomla, system

As it is fairly simple to create frontend views into the content area using Joomla!'s component infrastructure and a menu item, I wonder if it is not possible to abuse a system plugin to achive the same goal. Reason: keep the code slim (A plugin can consist only of two files.)

Suppose having mydomain.com/myuri, the system plugin should catch myuri, than override the content by a special content using onAfterRender.

My approach is to set some class variable within the derived plugin class to true, if the URI was hit. How can this be done, and which onEvent should be used?

Comment: You need to add some class on a div when user hits particular url ?

Comment: Basically you could yes, but as soon as you want to start making it more interesting you'll end up needing a model, maybe some controllers and so on. It's better to just add an MVC triad where you need it.  If all you want is to add a new view with the same MC  then just add the view to your template (with the xml file).  It's not beautiful MVC but you can do an awful lot right in your layout if you really need too, including trigger some events.  System plugins run on every single page load so that's another reason.

Comment: Basically, you are of course right. But in my case, the goal simply is to display some information in a lightbox. The information is retrieved by a simple curl-call (which would be the model). In summary, I'll need less than 15 LOC.